# Redux Saga watcher differences

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

What's the difference between this Sagas watchers:

```
export function* authWatcher() {
  yield [
    takeLatest(GET_USER_START, getUser),
    takeLatest(EDIT_USER_START, editUser),
    takeLatest(FORGOT_PASSWORD_START, forgotPassword),
    takeLatest(LOGOUT_START, logout)
  ];
}
```

and:

```
export function* authWatcher() {
  yield fork(takeLatest, GET_USER_START, getUser);
  yield fork(takeLatest, EDIT_USER_START, editUser);
  yield fork(takeLatest, FORGOT_PASSWORD_START, forgotPassword);
  yield fork(takeLatest, LOGOUT_START, logout);
}
```

At first, they do the same but, I don't know which are the best way to do it. Is there a better way?

Another thing that I see that takeLatest doesn't seem to be working. But I don't know if it's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takeEvery` and `takeLatest` use `fork` already internally so wrapping it in another fork is not necessary.

Yielding an array of effects is deprecated in newer redux-saga versions. Use the `all` effect instead.

```
export function* authWatcher() {
  yield all([
    takeLatest(GET_USER_START, getUser),
    takeLatest(EDIT_USER_START, editUser),
    takeLatest(FORGOT_PASSWORD_START, forgotPassword),
    takeLatest(LOGOUT_START, logout)
  ]);
}
```